Achieving additive permissions with IAM Identity Center in AWS
I'm trying to migrate users from IAM to IAM Identity Center. We use user groups on IAM heavily to do RBAC on our AWS account. When a user wants more permissions, we will create an IAM policy, create a group, attach the said policy to the group and attach the user to the group. This way, we're able to achieve this "additive" nature in policies where all policies from all groups are considered when determining the access a user might have. Migrating this setup to IAM Identity Center seems tricky.
You have permission sets, which from what I understand, are essentially roles that a user might assume to do work. If we map the IAM groups to IAM Identity Center groups and map the policies to permission sets, we get a list of different roles one can assume and we lose out on the "additive" nature of IAM policies. You either have access to resources from policy A or policy B but you cannot have access to resources from policy A and policy B together.
One way to fix this is to create a new permission set for each user and manage their permissions on an individual level but this seems clunky and tedious to do and also renders groups useless because you can't attach "policies" to them, they will only be for organizing users.

You realize that you can attach multiple Policies to a single Role, right?
